# apply function for combination of group

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I am trying to remove a for-loop from my function as it seems to be taking a tremendous amount of time to execute in a larger data set

what the function basically does is to make a new matrix containing sums of data from combinations of groups

```
library(dplyr)
data(iris)
for (Gnum_1 in 1:length(unique(iris$Species))) {
  for (Gnum_2 in 1:length(unique(iris$Species))) {
    if (Gnum_2 <= Gnum_1) {
      next
    }
    else {
Data_1<-iris %>% dplyr::filter(Species ==as.character(unique(iris$Species)[Gnum_1]))
Data_2<-iris %>% dplyr::filter(Species ==as.character(unique(iris$Species)[Gnum_2]))

print(sum(Data_1$Sepal.Width,Data_2$Sepal.Width))
    }}}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the `combn` function which will give you all unique combinations and for each combination take `sum` of `Sepal.Width` value.

```
combn(as.character(unique(iris$Species)), 2, function(x) {
  sum(iris$Sepal.Width[iris$Species %in% x])
})

#[1] 309.9 320.1 287.2
```